# How can I remove symmetric rows from matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Could you please tell me how can I remove symmetric rows from matrix in Matlab?
For example if

```
X=[1 2 3; 
   4 5 6;  
   1 2 3]
```

I would like to get

```
Y=[1 2 3; 
   4 5 6]
```

by removing the third row.

Comment: If you mean something different from duplicate rows when you say 'symmetric' then please edit your question to explain further and add an example demonstrating the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete duplicate rows then try using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
Y = unique(X,'rows')
```